# Google Cloud VM: 1 GPU for multiple instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, gpu, kvm

is it possible to use 1 gooogle cloud service GPU for multiple instances?

-like you can use one GPU to power multiple VM´s via virtual GPU´s

Comment: I don't know if this should have the KVM tag... I'm fairly certain Google-Cloud-Platform is proprietary.

Comment: This is interesting article about Azure & Nvidia Quadro GPU's. https://techcrunch.com/2019/01/29/nvidias-quadro-virtual-workstations-are-now-available-on-azure/?renderMode=ie11

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible - like you cannot use one GPU card in multiple desktop PCs at the same time.

Comment: But I can use one GPU to power multiple VM´s via virtual GPU´s. Did you considered this in your answer? GCP is just a giant vm i tought.

Comment: I'm not aware of any virtualization solution that could do GPU sharing. You can of course emulate simple VGA cards but that is not the use case for cloud GPUs

Comment: You do know they design GPU's specifically to be shared amongst VM's. Comparing physical computer resource allocations to hosts and VM management shows clear lack of understanding.

Comment: @mensi `I'm not aware of any virtualization solution that could do GPU sharing` --> Let me google that for you --> https://docs.nvidia.com/grid/latest/grid-vgpu-user-guide/index.html

Comment: and I quote "NVIDIA Virtual GPU (vGPU) enables multiple virtual machines (VMs) to have simultaneous,direct access to a single physical GPU, using the same NVIDIA graphics drivers that aredeployed on non-virtualized operating systems."

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers: The relevant section from your link would be 1.1.2. GPU Pass-Through. Also see https://cloud.google.com/gpu/: "GPUs are offered in passthrough mode, directly attached to the virtual machine to provide maximum performance."